# Can MySQLi queries be the same as they were in MySQL when preparing?

Tags: php, mysqli

In PHP's MySQL, I used to format my queries like this, with grave accents and single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM `Members` WHERE `Username`='JohnDoe'
```

However, in MySQLi, prepared statements are introduced, and all the tutorials or documentaries I see format queries without the single quotes and grave accents.

Is it still safe to use my old ways of queries? Does it have an impact on security against SQL injections for stuff like below?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$st = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Members` WHERE `Username`='?'");
```

Or should I perform it without the `s and 's?

Comment: Backticks (`) are best practice but not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With prepared statements, you do not use single quotes around the parameter place holders.  You can however still use backticks around database objects names.  This is purely at your preference outside of those time where the database object itself is named in such a manner that the backticks would be required.

I personally find it best to consistently use backticks as I feel that it make is easier to read the queries at a glance.

Comment: So essentially, when I bind a string parameter, it'll put the quotes around it for me?

Comment: @Bailey In essence, yes, though the behavior is tied to how you specify the type of data when binding the parameters.